# Show proxied target class in Intellij IDEA debugger?

Tags: java, spring, debugging, intellij-idea, proxy

Is it possible to see a java class that has been proxied by Spring, rather than the proxy itself? I'm using Intellij IDEA 13. The objective is to skip the proxy class and dip into the invoked methods of the target class. The same accounts for stepping up a stack trace.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting what's wrong with the question is not fair - especially when voting for questions from newcomers.